# Rename-Item is not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory, share

I have a share on a folder at path `\\Srv1011\User0$` (Active Directory) and I want to rename it with another name `\\Srv1011\User1$` but it is not working for me.

Code is:

```
Rename-Item -Path \\Srv1011\User0$ -NewName \\Srv1011\User1$
```

Right now the share is enable on the folder and if I execute the above command I get this error:

```
Rename-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Rename-Item -Path \\srv13577\User0$ -NewName \\srv13577\User1$
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Rename-Item], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

But If I remove the share from folder I get the following error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '\\srv13577\User0$' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Rename-Item -Path \\srv13577\User0$ -NewName \\srv13577\User1$
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Right now I am not sure how to rename such folder. My original work is to drop the share, rename the folder and create the share back.
But for now I am stuck with renaming.

Comment: Do not use a full path for the second argument. i.e.: rename-item -Path \\srv13577\testriham1$ -NewName <your new name without path>

Comment: @DavidBrabant I have tried this but still it do not work. The I get This Rename-Item : Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but `Rename-Item` is not intended to change share names. Have a look at the SmbShare module.

Comment: @Clijsters SmbShare wont work on unix platform. I have tried this already so that is why I am using RMTSHARE to create,delete a share. And as I mentioned in my original question I even removed the share from the folder and then tried to rename-item but it still did not work.

Comment: @Capri82: As you didn't specify your operating system and where talking about AD, I thought it's windows. This is not possible, as your code snippet definitely refers to an smb share path and not a local path.

Comment: @Capri82, In short: You are referring to an smb path, which can't be renamed with `Rename-Item`. If you unshare the folder, the smb path doesn't exist anymore, that's why your 2nd error comes up.

Comment: @Clijsters yup it is a blocker. I will need to move instead. Thanks for your input

Comment: You cannot rename shares. You must delete and re-create them if you want a different name for a share.

Comment: @Clijsters Can you post your last comment as an answer so that I can accept it and close my question properly? You were the first one to let me know what was wrong and why it is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain your misconception:

What you are trying to achieve is renaming an smb share, (Look at your path, which starts with `\\`). `Rename-Item` is not able to rename shares this way.

You probably want to rename the folder, which is shared under *User0$* on the server, or you want to chamge the share's name. These are two different actions.

When you unshare your folder and try to rename it again, it can't be found, because - yeah - the share under `\\srv13577\User0$` is not there anymore. That's why your 2nd error came up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to rename a share folder using *rename-item* cmdlet.

Rather I would suggest you to take the content of the share folder,

then create a new share folder with your new name

then move the content from the old one to new one

and finally delete the source share folder.

That will ease out your work.